# Combining two differential equations, dissolution and decay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

## Question

A certain chemical is introduced into a system such that its concentration follows

$$C(t)=1-e^{-\frac{1}{b}t^a}$$

This chemical also has a half-life of $\lambda$. So, *if* the concentration were 100% at $t=0$, then the concentration in the system *would* have followed

$$C(t)=\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{t}{\lambda}}$$

However, again, the chemical is being introduced at a gradual rate according to the first formula.

How do I combine the two formulae?

## Attempt

Here were my thoughts.

We can take the derivative of the first formula to arrive at a rate of change due to dissolution:

$$\frac{dC_{dis}}{dt}=\frac{a}{b}t^{a-1}e^{-\frac{1}{b}t^a}$$

And the actual rate of decay depends on the concentration $C$ itself (corrected by @WW1):

$$\frac{dC_{dec}}{dt}=-\frac{\ln 2}{\lambda}C$$

And these are two independent processes, so I can add the two to create the total system:

$$\frac{dC}{dt}=-\frac{\ln 2}{\lambda}C+\frac{a}{b}t^{a-1}e^{-\frac{1}{b}t^a}$$

And this is where I'm stuck, as *Intro. to Differential Equations* was ten years ago for me :-)

Can one do this?

$$\frac{dC}{dt} + \frac{\ln 2}{\lambda}C = \frac{a}{b}t^{a-1}e^{-\frac{1}{b}t^a}$$

This form *looks* familiar, *i.e.* reminds me of forms like

$$dy - y = 0$$

but I'm afraid I'm just making senseless typographical manipulations at this point. Because if I take the integrals like this...

$$\int\frac{dC}{dt}dt + \frac{\ln 2}{\lambda}\int C dt = \int\frac{a}{b}t^{a-1}e^{-\frac{1}{b}t^a}dt$$

...then two of the integrals just simplify back to the original formulae:

$$C - \frac{\ln 2}{\lambda}\int C dt = 1-e^{-\frac{1}{b}t^a}$$

Which seems recursive to me, and in need of some differential equations technique.

Can someone suggest a technique? I'm happy to try it on my own (and post an answer if I succeed).

Comment: Woops. I already see one error—there's no $\lambda$ in my new formulation—so I guess I also need help with the formulation, not just a technique for solving whatever differential equation I've created.

Comment: $$\frac{dC_{dec}}{dt}= - \frac{ \ln 2}{\lambda}C $$

Comment: @WW1 - Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I now see that this is an ordinary first-order differential equation. I'll dig up my textbook and give it a go later.